# GPS - Compute travel time satellite-receiver

Tags: matlab

I'm working with a MATLAB Software-defined Radio, and I need to compute the travel time of the satellite signal, in order to get the pseudo range of the receiver (the direct distance between the satellite and the receiver position) before compute the receiver position.

I've already done sucesfully the acquisition and tracking of the signal, but I'm having problems about computing the travel time of the signal (since it multiplied by the light speed is the range). I can easily obtain the transmitted time from the navigation data, but I don't know how I can get the received time.

Form Kai Borre's book "A Software-Defined GPS And Galileo Receiver" On Pg 121, I've read:

"For software receivers the situation is a little different. The time tcommon common to all pseudorange observations is defined as the time of transmission at the satellites. Hence the computation of position of satellite k is done at:

t_k=tcommon-dt_k

The only “receiver time” used is the relative time of reception from each of the satellites and which makes the individual pseudorange. A consequence of this time definition is that the computed satellite coordinates immediately refer to the ECEF system, and therefore satellite coordinates are not to be rotated about the Z-axis by an angle equal to the travel time times the Earth’s rotation rate. "

So, what I'm asking is how I can compute the travel time (or how I is usually done) between the satellite and the receiver (to get the pseudorange), since in software receivers there is "no time" references (as it happens with hardware receivers).

Comment: I think you're on to a good question, but actually just forgot to ask it. Maybe you want to add a sentence that ends in "?" and asks something that can be precisely answered, like "Knowing the {word} of {words}, how can I derive {other word}?", so that we know what exactly to explain :)

Comment: I've add a summary paragraph at the end in order to explain it better.

Comment: But there *is* a time reference – what do you think does sampling rate mean?

Comment: It's the way I'm trying, I'm multiplying the ms where I find the first subframe (of each satellite) but he sampling rate, then I get the number of sample, but I don't know how to extract from there the travel time.

Comment: Yeah, but I really don't see how that problem is any different from the problem that hardware receivers have. You have four unknown (time "now", three coordinates of your receiver), and a set of knowns (time at transmission from the satellites, position of satellites), and you solve that system of equations. Hardware receivers (which, by the way, as far as I ever encountered GPS receivers, are very much software-defined) don't have any better time reference – they have to determine their own time and clock error just like pure software receivers.

Comment: In a hardware receiver, the hardware knows the time when it has receive the data, and the can compute the time by doing: "Time_reception - Time_output_satellite". In my case, I don't have a Time_reception, since are a set of samples. So, how would you solve the computation of the problem of the pseudoranges? (the rest of unknowns it doesn't matter to me right now, I only want to get the direct distances between satellite-receiver)

Comment: "the hardware knows the time" <- misconception right there.

Comment: How does the hardware know the time? It calculated it from the information it got by receiving satellite signals.

Comment: I though they had an "internal clock", I was wrong then. So, how they calculates the pseudoranges then? After knowing the position (in the data) of the first subframe for each satellite (in samples or seconds) , how can I get the pseduorange? How would you do it?

Comment: your receiver for the software processing has an internal clock, too. But no matter what you do, these clocks are not of a quality that's close to being comparable to the clocks of GPS satellites. Thus, you have to somehow discipline your clock (hardware receiver) or resample your signal so that it matches the clock of the GPS satellites. Also, that clock doesn't have a notion of "GPS time" when you turn it on.

Comment: And what you're now asking is "how does GPS work?", and that is a) explained extensively in literature and b) a different question. Maybe you'd want to re-read wikipedia's  ["More detailed description"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#More_detailed_description) of what the receiver actually calculates. You might be in "too deep" already :-) It's really just that you need the fourth satellite to be able to get all the four unknowns that I mentioned above.

Comment: I've already have a base about GPS operation. The question I'm asking is about how to compute the first set of pseudoranges, before to compute the position.

Comment: You just set an arbitrary time for your first sample, and then derive your times of arrival relative to that time based on the sample rate